# remove separator in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

i have this query `select(','+firstname +Lastname) from <tablename>`

i have to remove `,` in result

Answer (score 2):

So remove it:

```
SELECT  firstname + Lastname
FROM    tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
select coalesce(Lastname + ', ' + firstname, firstname, lastname)
from <tablename>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a simple string replace to me

```
SELECT REPLACE(',' + firstname + Lastname, ',', '')
FROM <tablename>
```

Although I don't really get why you're concatenating a comma to the beginning of your result if you don't need it anyway.